# What's the problem with my code? In the third last line in score[i], the program said that i is undeclared

Tags: arrays, c, undeclared-identifier

I just started learning C language. So, I am running into a lot of problems. I thought declaring i under for loop is enough, and I can use the value of i for outside too. But I think, that was not the case. Can someone explain the situation, please.

```
# include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    printf("Enter how many numbers in arrays you want to input  :   ");
    scanf("%i", &x);

    int score[x];

    for(int i= 0; i <= x; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the score :   ");
        scanf("%i", &score[i]);
    }
    // in the below line the output said "i" is undeclared.
    float average = score[i] / x;
    printf("The average score is    :   %f", average);
}
```

Comment: `float average = score[i] / x;` is bad even if `i` was available as `score[x+1]` is bad.

Comment: The last iteration of `scanf("%i", &score[i]);` is UB as `&score[x]` is a problem.

Comment: `score[i] / x` is `int` division with an `int` quotient.  Assigning that to a `float` will not recover any fraction.

Comment: Aside: don't use `%i` for input unless you know the user will want to enter octal or hexadecimal. Please use `%d` for decimal input.

Comment: Bug: `for(int i= 0; i <= x; i++)` is off by one and should be `for(int i= 0; i < x; i++)`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is fairly simple

because of where you decalred `i` it is only visable to the for loop.
To make `i` visable to the whole function all you need to do is:

```
int i = 0;
for (; i <=x; i++){
    printf("Enter the score :   ");
    scanf("%i", &score[i]);
}
```

this makes `i` avaliable throughout the function

Answer (score 0):

`i` is declared in the initialization section of a `for` statement.  That means the scope and lifetime of that variable is the expressions in the `for` statement itself as well as the block statement it contains.  Once the loop is done, the variable no longer exists.

You need to declare `i` outside of the loop if you want to use it outside of the loop.

```
int i;
for(i= 0; i <= x; i++)
```

That being said, you don't actually need to use `i` outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are security issues associated with using scanf so don't use it for anything serious. That said, I tried to re-write your program properly, and it still has pretty rubbish input validation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define INPUTTEXTLEN 20
#define MAXINPUTINT 1000

int inputint() {  
    char inputtext[INPUTTEXTLEN + 1] = {0};
    long inputval;
    while (1) {
        fgets(inputtext, INPUTTEXTLEN, stdin);
        if (strlen(inputtext) > 0) {
            inputval = atoi(inputtext);
            if ((inputval < MAXINPUTINT) && (inputval >= 0)) break;
        }
    }
    return (int)inputval;
}

int main(void)
{
    int x = 0;
    printf("Enter how many numbers in arrays you want to input  :   ");
    //scanf("%i", &x);
    while (x <= 0) {
        x = inputint();
    }

    int score[x];
    float average = 0;

    for(int i= 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the score :   ");
        //scanf("%i", &score[i]);   
        score[i] = inputint();
        average += score[i];
    }
    average /= x;
    printf("The average score is    :   %f\n", average);
}
```